# Powershell: call a function using a string

Tags: powershell

I'm by no means a Powershell expert, so there may be some misuse of terms:

I'm editing a script to install pieces of software based upon the value of a variable. I want to permit multiple strings so what gets installed can be cherry-picked.
Examples:

```
installsoftware.ps1 -DeployModules "Base, Pack1, Pack3"
installsoftware.ps1 -DeployModules "All"
```

How would people suggest I accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd so something like this:

```
param ([string[]]$DeployModules)

Switch -Regex ($DeployModules)
{
  'Base|All'
   { 
     'deploy Base module'
   }

  'Pack1|All'
   {
     'deploy Pack1 module'
   }

  'Pack3|All'
   {
     'deploy Pack3 module'
   }
 }
```